# ¿Cómo pasar como parametro una matriz que no conozco su longitud en C?

Tags: c, array, funciones

Una matriz consta de **[filas][columnas]**.

Sabiendo ésto, tengo lo siguiente:

```
void Combinacion(int CantidadElementos[], int i)
```

Ésta funcion recibe un vector lleno con números, de `x` tamaño y una variable `i`, que me ayuda a indicar la posición de `CantidadElementos[]` que voy a utilizar.

En esta funcion hice lo siguiente:

```
int elementos = CantidadElementos[i]; 
//Le estoy pasando el valor a la varible `elementos`.
```

Para luego crear una Matriz de 10 Filas y Dependiendo del valor que reciba de otra función con `CantidadElementos` y `i`, crear la cantidad de Columnas:

```
char Almacen [10][elementos];
```

**EL PROBLEMA**

Una vez creada la matriz, la lleno de caracteres, y a medida que la voy llenando se la paso como parametro a otro metodo, mandandole la posicion en la que está con las variables `u` para columna y `l` para fila:

```
if( VerificadorVacio( u,l,Almacen )==true )
```

Luego las recibo:

```
bool VerificadorVacio (int l, int n,char Almacen[10][])
```

**Al compilar, me aparecen estos errores:**

> [Error] declaration of 'Almacen' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
>
> In function `bool VerificadorVacio(...)`:
>
> [Error] 'Almacen' was not declared in this scope
>
> [Error] 'n' was not declared in this scope
>
> [Error] 'l' was not declared in this scope

Comment: En C debe indicarse (al crear una matriz estática) el tamaño exacto de todas las dimensiones excepto la primera, para conocer el multiplicador o desplazamiento que separa cada elemento de la primera dimensión del siguiente. Por otro lado, deberás indicar en qué líneas te dan los siguientes errores para saber por qué te salen como no declarados. Deberás compartir más código para que podamos ayudarte e indicarte la forma correcta de definir esa matriz (deberás usar matrices de punteros a punteros de tipo char reservados con `malloc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char Almacen [10][elementos];
```

Dado que `elementos` es una variable, `Almacen` es una *VLA* (**V**ariable **L**ength **A**rray) o array de longitud variable y, desde C99, no es algo soportado por el estándar luego es algo que depende del compilador y sus extensiones para funcionar... si cambias el entorno tienes papeletas para que el código no compile.

Para adaptarte al estándar tienes que usar memoria dinámica.

> [Error] declaration of 'Almacen' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first

Este error es claro y conciso como el solo. Te está diciendo que los arrays multidimensionales tienen que detallar todas sus dimensiones salvo la primera... y tu lo estás haciendo al revés:

```
bool VerificadorVacio (int l, int n,char Almacen[10][ ])
//                                               ^^  ^
```

Para que esta función compile tienes que indicar la segunda dimensión... pero claro, está basada en una variable y no lo siguiente no te va a funcionar:

```
bool VerificadorVacio (int l, int n,char Almacen[][elementos])
```

Ya que por un lado `elementos` no existe a nivel global y, segundo, al ser la declaración de la función es requisito que el valor de `elementos` sea conocido en tiempo de compilación... lo cual es imposible al ser una variable dependiente de la ejecución.

Así que, volviendo a lo que te he dicho al inicio, la solución pasa por usar memoria dinámica.

Un array declarado en la pila, es decir, con sus dimensiones conocidas en tiempo de compilación:

```
char Almacen[2][2];
```

Se almacena en memoria de forma secuencial y compacta:

```
Memoria previa ... |  0x01  |  0x02  |  0x03  |  0x04  | ....
                   | [0][0] | [0][1] | [1][0] | [1][1] | 
                   |              Almacen              |
```

Mientras que un puntero doble tiene algo tal que:

```
| 0x01 | 0x02 | ... |  0x10  |  0x11  | ... |  0x15  |  0x16  |
| 0x10 | 0x15 |     | [0][0] | [0][1] |     | [1][0] | [1][1] |
|   Almacen   |     |    Almacen[0]   |     |    Almacen[1]   |
```

Es decir, aunque en los dos casos para acceder al primer elemento puedas hacer:

```
Almacen[0][0] = 10;
```

Esto sirve para que entiendas por qué el compilador te está exigiendo la segunda dimensión de `Almacen`. Cuando tu quieres acceder a `Almacen[x][y]` el compilador tiene que hacer la siguiente operación:

```
Almacen + (x * NUM_COLUMNAS + y)
```

Esta operación lo que hace es calcular un desplazamiento respecto a la posición de memoria donde comienza el array. Nota que solo es necesario conocer el número de columnas (segunda dimensión), cosa que no sucede con el número de filas (primera dimensión).

Pues bien, no te queda otra opción que usar memoria dinámica y aquí puedes decidir si quieres usar un puntero doble o un puntero simple. Cada solución tiene sus ventajas y sus inconvenientes:

**Puntero doble**

- Su uso es idéntico al del VLA que estabas declarando
- Requiere varias reservas de memoria (datos fragmentados en memoria)

**Puntero simple**

- Para acceder a los elementos necesitas calcular el desplazamiento de forma manual
- Solo requiere una reserva de memoria (datos compactos en memoria)

Un ejemplo usando punteros dobles:

```
char** Almacen = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  Almacen[i] = (char*)malloc(elementos*sizeof(char));

// ...

for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  free(Almacen[i]);
free(Almacen);

// ...

bool VerificadorVacio (int l, int n,char** Almacen)
```

Comment: ¿Qué decirte? Chapeau como siempre, aunque tiene muchos fallos en su código (que no ha compartido).

Comment: @OscarGarcia soy consciente... sin embargo si me ha parecido que la pregunta tenía datos suficientes como para responder. Por cierto gracias :)